# Solving a quadratic function using mips

Tags: assembly, mips

I want to make a simple program with mips assembly to learn the language. I have the function ax²+bx. The user has to input the a,b and the domain of function.I want to print the values that the function is zero but only the integers of the domain. I thought that the simplest way is to loop all the integers from [x1,x2] and print the values that the function=zero.I get an error "Unknown system call 268501060".

```
    .data
msg_read_a: .asciiz"dwse arithmo a:"
msg_read_b: .asciiz"dwse arithmo b:"
msg_read_x1: .asciiz"dwse diastima x1:"
msg_read_x2: .asciiz"dwse diastima x2:"

riza: .asciiz"h sunartish mhdenizetai sto: \n"

.text 
main:

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg_read_a    #α
syscall
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t0,$v0

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg_read_b    #β
syscall 
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t1,$v0

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg_read_x1    #διαστημα χ1
syscall
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t2,$v0

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg_read_x2     #διαστημα χ2
syscall
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t3,$v0

    move $t4, $t2 #πρωτο χ για επαναληψη
    
    
while:
    beq $t4, $t3, exit
    
    mul $t6,$t4,$t4  #x^2
    mul $t7,$t0,$t6 #a*x^2
    mul $t6,$t1,$t4   #b*x
    
    add $t8, $t7, $t6 #τ8 τελικη τιμη συναρτησης
    
    beq $t8,0,isioi #if(t8=0)
    
    isioi:
    li $v0, 1
    la $v0, riza
    syscall
    move $a0, $t8
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    add $t4, $t4, 1
    j while
    
exit: 
    li $v0, 10
     syscall
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  Single step until hitting that syscall that gets the error, and, look at the value in $v0.

Comment: @ErikEidt i just did it and fixed the error but still the result is wrong, so i guess i messed the loop

Comment: Well, that's debugging.  It doesn't work until every thing is right.  But at least you've made some progress.